# How to approach GROUP BY in PostgreSQL using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails 3 app which keeps high scores. I'm hosting it on Heroku which uses postgresql as the db.

I need to extract the top scores from the scores table. The table has columns `score` and `user_id`. It was working in mysql with the following:

`Score.order('score DESC').group('user_id').limit(25)`

This ranks each user's top score.

When I put the app on Heroku, I get the following psql error `PGError: ERROR:  column "scores.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

I've read around but haven't found a clear answer. What is the most optimal way to recreate the above query to work with PostgreSQL?

Thanks!

Tim

Comment: I'm trying to use DISTINCT ON as stated by others. Score.select('DISTINCT ON (user_id) id, user_id, score').order('user_id, score DESC').limit(25) and I get the following error: "PGError: ERROR:  column id_list.alias_0 does not exist
LINE 1: ... AS id_list ORDER BY id_list.al...". I'm not even stating a column with the name of 'id_list' so I don't get why that's coming up.

Answer (score 2):

That means your select query is selecting the "id" column but not including it in the group by clause. I'm not familiar with rails but could it be selecting * or all columns?

Answer (score 0):

Could you do

```
select id, max(score) group by id;
```

Comment: I'd like to see the query that got the error, because that query up there should generate no error.

Comment: Score.select('user_id, score, max(score)').group('user_id').limit(25) works with mysql but shoots off the same error with postgresql.

Comment: That is not the same as my query, you're asking for score without grouping by it or using an aggregate.  make it something like

score.select('user_id,max(score)').group('user_id').limit(25)

If you need all the scores then a group by isn't the right choice anyway.

Comment: Hey Scott, first of all, thanks for your replies. Your query works but I need to list the scores. If I don't use 'score' in the select statement like I did above, I get the error 'missing attribute: score'. If I call @high_scores = Score.select('user_id,max(score)').group('user_id').limit(25), I can't call @high_score.score. Is there a way to resolve this?